# Transitive closure of a union

Tags: set-theory

I have a quick question regarding transitive closures. In the text I'm currently reading, (Kunen - Set Theory, 2011), the transitive closure of a set $x$ is defined as trcl$(x) = \{ a : a \in^* x \}$, where $a \in^* x$ means there is an $\in$-path from $a$ to $x$ (I think the text implies that this is a finite path).

I'm curious as to whether or not the following is true for any two sets $x$ and $y$:
$$ \mbox{trcl}(x \cup y) = \mbox{trcl}(x) \cup \mbox{trcl}(y),$$
or if there is some sort of counter-example that shows this is false? Would this hold for and infinite union as well? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** Note that if $a\in\operatorname{trcl}(x)$ then either $a\in x$ or $a\in\operatorname{trcl}(x')$ for some $x'\in x$. Conclude equality holds (for the infinite case as well).

[You can also note that $\operatorname{trcl}(x)$ is the smallest transitive $y$ set such that $x\subseteq y$. In that case it becomes easier to prove these equalities.]

Comment: Thanks for the helpful hint! I was able to show equality.